# Java Kafka Consumer works fine with new Consumer Group ID but when shutdown and restarted it does not consume any messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

This is probably my lack of understanding but it is frustrating. I have a Java Kafka Consumer, that when is assigned a newly created groupId and consumerID it consumes messages just fine. However when stopping the java app in my eclipse IDE and restarting it with the same groupID and consumerID it does not pull any messages. If I shut down the app again, and assign it new and different groupID/consumerID it works just fine. Can anyone help me figure out why this happens?

Config Values Below

```
props.put("bootstrap.servers","192.168.5.0:30092,192.168.4.6:30092,192.168.5.8:30092");
props.put("acks", "all");
props.put("retries", 4);
props.put("batch.size", 1000);
props.put("linger.ms", 1);
props.put("buffer.memory", 335544323);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "Router2");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "Consumer2");
props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
props.put("session.timeout.ms", "300000");
props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");
```

Comment: Yes,I can confirm that by looking at the dashboard and seeing the message publish metrics. about 100 messages a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when a consumer starts reading messages, it commits the offsets of the messages that have been succesfully consumed so that it won't consume them again.

Everytime you create a new consumer group, the consumer will start consuming from the earliest available offset (since no offsets were committed previously for a newly created consumer group).

> After the consumer receives its assignment from the coordinator, it
>   must determine the initial position for each assigned partition. When
>   the group is first created, before any messages have been consumed,
>   the position is set according to a configurable offset reset policy
>   (`auto.offset.reset`). Typically, consumption starts either at the
>   earliest offset or the latest offset.

For more details refer to [Offset Management](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/consumer.html#offset-management) in Confluent Docs.

---

If you want to achieve the same behaviour, you can simply stick to the same consumer group and simply set `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest` instead of `latest` which is the default value:

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
```

or

```
props.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest")
```

(depending on what version you are currently running)

In this way, your consumer will always start consuming the messages from the earliest available offset.

Alternatively, you can use `seekToBeginning()`:

```
kafkaConsumer.poll(0); // Heartbeat sent
kafkaConsumer.seekToBeginning(kafkaConsumer.assignment());
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(5);
```

---

Note that this has the same effect as the `--from-beginning` flag that can be used with the Kafka Console Consumer.

Comment: I tried adding props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest"); to my config but same behavior, no messages are pulled and I know that messages are constantly being produced to the topic by another app. I also understand --from-begining but that requires partition assignment i think.  Is a different between assignPartitions and topicSubscribe?

Comment: @DuncanKrebs See my updated answer. Try one more approach and let me know

Comment: @DuncanKrebs Also, out of curiosity can you try `props.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");`

Comment: When removing the consumer group property and setting this props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest") i am able to start/restart the consumer with the same consumer ID and it continues to pull messages every time.

Comment: @DuncanKrebs it will do the same even if you remove `props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest")` because a random group-id will be generated for your consumer in case you don't provide one.

Comment: put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");  this seems to have worked!!!!! I put the consumer group property back and now when I restart the app with the same group/consumer and it worked. Why??

Comment: @DuncanKrebs Does`props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")` work? Also, how about `props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "smallest")` ?

Comment: @DuncanKrebs I think it depends on what version you are running.